# Generate appropriate number of tokens using boost

Tags: c++, boost

I have a code as below

```
 std::string some_string = "-0.003  79350   -0.267  147";
 boost::algorithm::trim (some_string);
 //std::cout << some_string << std::endl;
 boost::tokenizer<> tok( some_string );
 const auto n = std::distance( tok.begin(), tok.end() );
 std::cout << n << std::endl;
```

I wish to have the number of tokens as 4, but it gives 6 . Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following code outputs 4 as required.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<boost/tokenizer.hpp>

int main() {
   std::string s = "-0.003  79350   -0.267  147";
   boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char> > tok(s, boost::char_separator<char>(" "));
   const auto n = std::distance( tok.begin(), tok.end() );
   std::cout << n << std::endl;
}
```

The same code on Coliru is [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ba57c393efab6600).

Comment: @Puppy actually I'm mostly surprised about the fact that it combines `using namespace std` and `using namespace boost` which is a very bad idea. Likely this is also the reason that namespaces are still qualified in the subsequent code...

Comment: @sehe, my code backbone is taken from [Boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/tokenizer/tokenizer.htm)

Answer (score 0):

No need for boost and also more correct.

It's more correct assuming that you actually wish to parse numbers

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49ba9e35dae53dbf)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    std::istringstream some_string ( "-0.003  79350   -0.267  147");
    std::cout << std::distance(std::istream_iterator<double>(some_string), {});
}
```

## Update

If you want to retain the tokens, and not just parse numbers:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e798895ad8d3af78)</kbd>**

```
istringstream s("-0.003  79350   -0.267  147");

vector<string> vec(istream_iterator<string>(s), {});

cout << vec.size();
```

Comment: I have to use the tokens for further use and the string may not always contain numbers. So, I followed the answer from @megabyte1024 . Your answer is nice.

Comment: @Launa That's why a good example is important in your code :) See my edit. (also **[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e798895ad8d3af78)**)

Comment: Your answers are useful. However, I have not gained privilege to vote up:)

Comment: I have a problem using your answers in visual studio 2013. I don't know why. Even the answer from @megabyte1024 worked fine earlier. Afterwards it gave pecuiliar result. Is it the issue with VS 2013 ?

Comment: @Launa Possibly. MSVC isn't really good with c++11 yet :( Fix it: *[Live in C++03](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ebcdf90271907011)*